# Getting two numbers which are separated by colon

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

I got a bit of a problem. I'm trying to split some text and numbers.

Considering this string input.

```
string input = "1 Johannes 1:3, 2 Johannes 2:6, 1 Mosebok 5:4";
```

I'm trying to get the 2:3, 2:6, 5:4 to split from the rest of the text.
Then I want them to be separated from the colon, and be added to a list.

The list would look like this, after being looped out.
2
3
2
6
5
4

In which I could create a Hashtable entry from [0] and [1], [2] and [3], [4] and [5].

I would like to thank you all for your feedback on this.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far and any errors you're getting and we'll give you a hand. Unfortunately StackOverflow isn't a write-my-code-for-me site.

Comment: A very simple google search about  "split a string in c#" will get you your method, combine it with a simple logic and hurah!

Comment: How specific does the solution need to be? If this is the form the input will always be in you could simply find the locations of the colons and then assume that character directly behind and in front are what you need to acquire. But if there are going to be larger than single digit numbers that's a different story

Comment: `[\d]:[\d]` Regex to rescue. use regex `Match` method.

Comment: You could Split based on "," search for the last space with LastIndexOf and split again based on ":". How well structured is your input?

Comment: What does “create a Hashtable entry from [0] and [1] ...” mean? You want a `Dictionary<int, int>` where `dict[1] = 3`? Why not do that directly, why do you need to create a list first?

Comment: create a Hashtable entry from [0] and [1]. Yes i want to create a Dictionary<int, int> from the list

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, I would do it as

```
string input = "1 Johannes 1:3, 2 Johannes 2:6, 1 Mosebok 5:4";
var table = Regex.Matches(input, @"(\d+):(\d+)")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .ToLookup(m => m.Groups[1].Value, m => m.Groups[2].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "1 Johannes 1:3, 2 Johannes 2:6, 1 Mosebok 5:4";

            string pattern = @"(?'index'\d+)\s+(?'name'\w+)\s+(?'para'\d+:\d+),?";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("index : {0}, name : {1}, para : {2}",
                    match.Groups["index"],
                    match.Groups["name"],
                    match.Groups["para"]
                );
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here some piece of code that can help you.

```
        var input = "1 Johannes 1:3, 2 Johannes 2:6, 1 Mosebok 5:4";
        var nextIndex = 0;
        var currentIndex = 0;
        var numbers = new List<int>();

        do
        {
            currentIndex = input.IndexOf(":", currentIndex + 1);
            var leftNumber = Convert.ToInt32(input[currentIndex - 1].ToString());
            var rightNumber = Convert.ToInt32(input[currentIndex + 1].ToString());

            numbers.Add(leftNumber);
            numbers.Add(rightNumber);

            nextIndex = input.IndexOf(":", currentIndex + 1);

        } while (nextIndex != -1);
```